# Bootstrap column height with respect to another division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the grid layout of bootstrap and have this markup:

```
<div id="prof_cont_enclose">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="prof_cont_row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 prof_elem">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="/techahoy/securedir/m_images/mypic.jpg" width="100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 prof_elem">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                         <h1>T.V.Vignesh</h1>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have set the picture in 1st column to have width as 100% which means it will expand to the column's width and will adjust its height accordingly to preserve aspect ratio. So, I dont have a fixed height for  the column.

What I want to do is I want to keep the height of the other columns in 1st row to match the height of the 1st column.

Here is a snapshot of current implementation:
[image]

I referred to http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/ but it does not work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this codepen:
http://codepen.io/dschu/pen/zGQLNN?editors=110

You forgot your custom css:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

I also removed one wrapping div around your heading.

Comment: This works fairly well, but only in one direction. Suppose the content of the second column is larger than the first: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbRBOw?editors=110

Comment: Here's a slight modification to fix that by combining all columns with panels, but now the panels are tight together. My second demo addresses that. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOrjVy?editors=110

Comment: understood. went through your demos @isherwood. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your implementation is that you have a div element between the row and column elements. The `display: flex` statement has implications for immediate children of that element, so your columns must be direct children of the rows on which the flex styling is applied.

It's almost never a good idea to interfere with a grid system using your own styles and markup. Instead, modify what's inside the grid.

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 prof_elem">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5s0z6w4o/3)

You'll need to implement additional CSS if you want to combine the panel elements with the columns and retain the default spacing:

```
.row > div.panel {    /* column elements */
    margin: 10px;
}

<div class="col-xs-6 prof_elem panel panel-default">
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5s0z6w4o/6)**

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. I wish I can accept 2 answers. :-( Both answers helped me. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: No worries. Happy to help regardless.